# why my component is rendered without css?

Tags: angular, sass, mixins, bootstrap-themes

I am facing a problem in my code . I am using a bootstrap modal dialog box. when the user fills and submit the form displayed in the modal box , i want to show an in progress indicator to inform user that the request is getting processed. so here is the code that opens the modal dialogue box.

```
cloneFlight() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    combineLatest(
      this.translateService.get('CONFIRM.CLONE_FLIGHT', { item: this.flight.name}),
      this.flightsService.getCampaignsToClone(this.flight)
    ).subscribe( ([header, campaigns]) => { 
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.cloneFlightService.openModal(header,this.flight, campaigns);
    });
  }
```

CloneFlightService

```
@Injectable()
export class CloneFlightService
 {

  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService, private flightService: FlightsService){}

   openModal(header: string, flight: Flight, campaigns: CampaignUnpaginated[]) {
    const initialState = {
      flight: flight,
      campaigns : campaigns,
      header: header
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(CloneFlightModalComponent,{ initialState});
  }
}
```

CloneFlightModalComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pc-clone-flight-modal',
  templateUrl: './clone-flight-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clone-flight-modal.component.scss']
}
)
export class CloneFlightModalComponent implements OnInit {

  flight : Flight;
  campaigns: CampaignUnpaginated[];
  header: string;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  compareResources = propComparator('id');

  showCloneForm: boolean = true;

  cloneSuccess:boolean = false;
  cloneFailure:boolean = false;

  isLoading:boolean = false;


 constructor(public modalRef: BsModalRef, private fb: FormBuilder, 
  private flightService : FlightsService){
 }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    flightName: [{ value: ''},[Validators.required]],
    campaign : [ '' , Validators.required]
    });
    this.showCloneForm = true;
  }

  handleSubmit(value: CloneFlightFormValue){

   const cloneFlightRequest : CloneFlightRequest  = {

    flightName : value.flightName ,
    campaignId : value.campaign.id,
    flightId: this.flight.id ,

   };

   this.isLoading = false;
   this.flightService.submitCloneFlight(cloneFlightRequest)
   .subscribe( data => { 
     this.showCloneForm = false;
     this.cloneSuccess = true;
     this.cloneFailure = false;
     this.isLoading = false;
   }, 
    err => {
      this.showCloneForm = false;
      this.cloneSuccess = false;
      this.cloneFailure = true;
      this.isLoading = false;
     },
    ()=> {
      this.showCloneForm = false;
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
    );
  }
}
```

clone-flight-modal.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showCloneForm">

<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit(formGroup.value)">

  <pc-spinner [standalone]="true" *ngIf="true"></pc-spinner>

  <pc-form-layout [showRequiredFieldsMessage]="false">    
  <div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">
      <fa-icon icon="clone"></fa-icon>
      {{header}} 
    </h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body-content">

    <div class="inline-inputs-container"> 
      <div class="inline-input ml-3">
        <pc-form-field label="{{ 'LABELS.CLONE_FLIGHT' | translate }}" [required]="true" [errorMessages]="['required']">
          <input type="text" formControlName="flightName" [placeholder]="'PLACEHOLDERS.CLONE_FLIGHT_NAME' | translate" ngModel>
        </pc-form-field>
      </div>

      <div class="inline-input ml-3">
          <pc-form-field label="{{ 'LABELS.CLONE_CAMPAIGN' | translate }}" [required]="true" [errorMessages]="['required']">
          <select formControlName="campaign" [compareWith]="compareResources" ngModel>
            <option value="" disabled> Please select a campaign </option>
            <option *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns" [ngValue]="campaign"> {{campaign.name}} </option>
          </select>
        </pc-form-field>
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <pc-button theme="default" kind="flat" (click)="hideModal()">{{ 'ACTIONS.CANCEL' | translate }}</pc-button>
  <pc-button theme="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">{{ 'ACTIONS.CONFIRM' | translate }}</pc-button>
</div>
</pc-form-layout>
</form>
</ng-container> 

<ng-container *ngIf="cloneSuccess">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            <fa-icon icon="clone"></fa-icon>
            Success
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body-content ml-3">
        <h5>
          successfully cloned flight.
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
          <pc-button theme="primary" (click)="hideModal()">{{ 'ACTIONS.CLOSE' | translate }}</pc-button>
      </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="cloneFailure">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            <fa-icon icon="clone"></fa-icon>
            FAILURE
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body-content ml-3">
         unable to clone flight:
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <pc-button theme="primary" (click)="hideModal()">{{ 'ACTIONS.CLOSE' | translate }}</pc-button>
      </div>
</ng-container>
```

clone-flight-modal.component.scss

```
@import './../../../../scss/themes';
@import './../../../../scss/variables';
@import './../../../../scss/mixins';

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-title {
  @include pc-page-title;
}

.close-btn {
  color: $gray-600;
}

.modal-footer {
  border-top: 0px;
}
```

spinner component.

import { Component, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pc-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss']
})
export class SpinnerComponent {
  @Input() showBackdrop = true;
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('class.standalone')
  standalone = false;
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('class.showMessage')
  showMessage = false;

  constructor() {}
}
```

spinner.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="showBackdrop && !standalone" class="backdrop"></div>

<div *ngIf="showMessage" class="message">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spinner">
  <div class="circle circle1"></div>
  <div class="circle circle2"></div>
  <div class="circle circle3"></div>
</div>
```

spinner.component.scss

```
@import './../../../../scss/themes';
@import './../../../../scss/variables';
@import './../../../../scss/mixins';

:host {
  &.standalone {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: $spinner-standalone-height;
  }
}

:host {
  &.showMessage {
    height: $spinner-show-message-height;
  }
}

.backdrop {
  z-index: $spinner-backdrop-z-index;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: $spinner-backdrop-bg-color;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.spinner {
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: $spinner-z-index;
}

.circle {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  @include themify() {
    background-color: themed('brand-spinner');
  }  
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: bounce 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

.spinner .circle1 {
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.spinner .circle2 {
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: calc(50% + (#{$spinner-message-height} / 2));
  height: $spinner-message-height;
  z-index: $spinner-z-index;
}

.alert {
  margin: 0px auto;
  @include pc-dropshadow;
  height: inherit;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
  }

  &::before {
    @include pc-equilateral-triangle('down', 9px, #cceefe);
    bottom: -9px;
    left: calc(50% - 9px);
    z-index: $pc-info-popup-zindex-level-two;
  }

  &::after {
    @include pc-equilateral-triangle('down', 10px, #b8e8fd);
    bottom: -10px;
    left: calc(50% - 9px);
    z-index: $pc-info-popup-zindex-level-one;
  }
}
```

this is my theme.css

```
$themes: (
  celcom:
    (
      brand-primary: #009ade,
      brand-secondary: #fcba35,
      brand-spinner: #009ade,
      primary: #009ade,
      secondary: #f3f3f3,
      success: #119e5c,
      danger: #d0021b,
      warning: #fcba35,
      info: lighten(#009ade, 5)
    ),
  openmind:
    (
      brand-primary: #3d3d3d,
      brand-secondary: #be233a,
      brand-spinner: #be233a,
      primary: #0277bd,
      secondary: #f3f3f3,
      success: #2e7d32,
      danger: #be233a,
      warning: #fb8c00,
      info: lighten(#0277bd, 5)
    ),
  du:
    (
      brand-primary: #00aace,
      brand-secondary: #fcba35,
      brand-spinner: #00aace,
      primary: #00aace,
      secondary: #f3f3f3,
      success: #119e5c,
      danger: #d0021b,
      warning: #fcba35,
      info: lighten(#009ade, 5)
    )
);

@mixin themify($themes: $themes) {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {
    :host-context(.theme-#{$theme}) & {
      $theme-map: () !global;
      @each $key, $submap in $map {
        $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
        $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map,  ($key: $value)) !global;
      }

      @content;
      $theme-map: null !global;
    }
  }
}

@mixin themify-global($themes: $themes) {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {
    .theme-#{$theme} & {
      $theme-map: () !global;
      @each $key, $submap in $map {
        $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
        $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map,  ($key: $value)) !global;
      }

      @content;
      $theme-map: null !global;
    }
  }
}

@function themed($key) {
  @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}
```

the issue in short is  component is not visible in the clone-flight-modal.component.html because styles are not resolved from the theme file  . both spinner component and clone-flight-modal.component are in a shared module within my angular app.

you can see in the image component is rendered without the style

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csbPr.png)

this is what i got from the developer tool for the circle

```
.circle[_ngcontent-c9] {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: bounce 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation-duration: 1.4s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-name: bounce;
}
```

it misses  background-color .

Also i can see from the chrome developer tools i get this, not sure if it is of any use .

```
.standalone[_nghost-c13] {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px; }

.showMessage[_nghost-c13] {
  height: 200px; }

.backdrop[_ngcontent-c13] {
  z-index: 50;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px; }

.spinner[_ngcontent-c13] {
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 51; }

.circle[_ngcontent-c13] {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
          animation: bounce 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both; }

.theme-celcom[_nghost-c13]   .circle[_ngcontent-c13], .theme-celcom   [_nghost-c13]   .circle[_ngcontent-c13] {
    background-color: #009ade; }

.theme-openmind[_nghost-c13]   .circle[_ngcontent-c13], .theme-openmind   [_nghost-c13]   .circle[_ngcontent-c13] {
    background-color: #be233a; }

.theme-du[_nghost-c13]   .circle[_ngcontent-c13], .theme-du   [_nghost-c13]   .circle[_ngcontent-c13] {
    background-color: #00aace; }

.spinner[_ngcontent-c13]   .circle1[_ngcontent-c13] {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
          animation-delay: -0.32s; }

.spinner[_ngcontent-c13]   .circle2[_ngcontent-c13] {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
          animation-delay: -0.16s; }

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); } }

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); } }

.message[_ngcontent-c13] {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: calc(50% + (56px / 2));
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 51; }

.alert[_ngcontent-c13] {
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: inherit; }

.alert[_ngcontent-c13]::before, .alert[_ngcontent-c13]::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; }

.alert[_ngcontent-c13]::before {
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    border-right: 9px solid transparent;
    border-top: 9px solid #cceefe;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: calc(50% - 9px);
    z-index: 2; }

.alert[_ngcontent-c13]::after {
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #b8e8fd;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: calc(50% - 9px);
    z-index: 1; }
```

thank you so much
prasanth

Comment: from the developer tool i can see   @include themify() {
    background-color: themed('brand-spinner');
  }   is not applied

Comment: That on top in your image is suppossed to look like a spinner? that's the only element not getting styles? or is it the whole modal

Comment: just that element not getting style .